# How to change background color to a <DIV /> then fade out, then finally remove from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I want to first change the background color of a `<div>` to red then *fade out* that `<div>`. Once the *fade out* is completed remove it from the DOM.

The following code does *fade out* the `<div>` and remove it from the DOM but it doesn't change the `background-color` to red.

```
 $(this).find("div#" + id)
    .css("background-color", "#ff0000")
    .fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
```

Comment: Your code works for me as expected by you. Are you sure the background color is not turning red? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Make sure you don´t have any CSS rules that overrides the style you´re trying to apply. Use some DOM inspector like Firebug to view the element properties.

Comment: yep, my bad. i had a conficting event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwtC3/8/):

```
<div id="div1">
    test<br>
        test<br>
        test<br>

        test<br>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be nice not just linkin to a solution. get the important chapters or a snipet and also post it here...what if the link is dead soon?

Comment: Can you post your sample html? see this jsfiddle which searches for a particular element and then changes color http://jsfiddle.net/wwtC3/11/